# RelaxNG Using decimal datatype and setting value limits?

Tags: xml, relaxng

i am using RelaxNG to create a simple schema for an xml document... first of all, would this be a correct way of specifying an attribute of type decimal:

```
<attribute name='amount'><data type="decimal"/></attribute>
```

given that i have specified the data-library:

```
<element name='products' datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
```

Now, how would i set a minimum and maximum limit on the amount attribute? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The RELAX NG schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<element xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0" name="products" datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
  <attribute name="amount">
    <data type="decimal">
      <param name="maxInclusive">10.0</param>
      <param name="minInclusive">0.0</param>
    </data>
  </attribute>
</element>
```

successfully validates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products amount="1.0"/>
```

as long as the value of `amount` is a valid decimal value between 0.0 and 10.0 (as tested with https://validator.nu/). You can use `maxExclusive` and/or `minExclusive` as well to set the boundaries.

For documentation, see http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77057.html, http://www.relaxng.org/compact-tutorial-20030326.html#id2814737, http://evc-cit.info/cit041x/lecture4_rnc.html, and http://relaxng.org/tutorial-20011203.html#IDA5UYR.